# Adaptive Card Image

Tags: botframework, skype, skype-for-business, adaptive-cards

If an adaptive card is rendered as an image and sent to the user, where is that image hosted?

Also, I want to display my adaptive cards on skype, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/get-started/bots) says that 'full support is coming soon', however, does that mean that image rendering is supported for Skype currently? because so far I have had no luck. If it should be supported where would I start with debugging it? Is there a way to convert the card to an image and host it myself?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's been several weeks / months since the 1st version of Adaptive Cards is out and they are still not supported on most of the channels. I would suggest to use another type as a workaround for the moment, as we have no visibility on the roadmap

Comment: When a card is rendered to image they are generated on the server at runtime and not stored anywhere. 

I apologize we haven't published the official roadmap for Skype but we're actively working on it (and Teams).

Comment: Thanks Matt, I would find it useful if there were a service that could render and host adaptive cards as a high-quality image for node.js. So that adaptive cards style reused and still look good on platforms that don't fully support them currently. Would it be best to create a feature request on the github page